Why p-values as $P(p≤\alpha | H=1)≤\alpha$ and not $P(H=1 | p≤\alpha)$?
That's my question, as if I start from the definition of a $p$-value ($P(p≤\alpha | H=1)≤\alpha$ ) and apply Bayes rule I arrive to:
$$ P(p≤\alpha | H=1)=P(H=1 | p≤\alpha)\frac{P(p≤\alpha)}{P(H=1)} ≤\alpha $$
so that:
$$ P(H=1 | p≤\alpha) ≤\frac{\alpha}{P(p≤\alpha)} P(H=1)$$
I this case we would know that if we obtain a p-value of less than $\alpha$ in our data, we can confidently state that the null hypothesis is false if $\frac{\alpha}{P(p≤\alpha)} P(H=1)$ is small.
The problem I see is that this approach doesn't make sense to me based on the null hypotheses I studied (what is $P(H=1)$ for $H: X\sim N(0,1)$). But the same way this mathematically doesn't make sense to me because of ill defined objects, the classical definition doesn't make any sense to me as I cannot see how it measures any kind of confidence to reject $H$, as it really depends a lot on how the $p$ value behaves when $H$ is false (for example, if $P(p≤\alpha | H=0)≤\alpha$ as well, how can we even distingish between them).
I know my question is not very clearly stated, but I really been trying to get $p-$values in my head for a while and cannot capture the essence of them. Thank you!

You haven't explicitly defined $H$. Chances are you mean "the null hypothesis is true" by $H=1$, but note that p-values are based on a frequentist concept of probability, in which the null hypothesis is either true or false, but this is treated as fixed and not random. So there is no *probability that the null hypothesis is true"; $P(H=1)$ doesn't exist in this concept.

The definition of a p-value is not usually P(p<a|H=1) as I have ever learnt it, as this is something we don't (in many instances can't) know. Instead the normal definition of a p-value is that for some test statititic x, calculated from some distribtion X p=P( X > x| H0) (one-sided test). assumeing that by H=1 you mean X is parameterised by the alternative hypothesis.

"it really depends a lot on how the p value behaves when H is false" - this is true. $P_{H=0}(p\le\alpha)$ is called "power", and good tests are tests with high power. Particularly $P_{H=0}(p\le\alpha)>\alpha$ is often required in the literature and called "unbiasedness" in some places.

If you are interested in $P(H=1|$data), have a look at Bayesian statistics, which doesn't operate with p-values.

Well, the OP, while a new contributor, has hit there on one of the most (if not the most) vexing issue in statistics. It has given rise to endless debates about p-values and NHST (Null hypothesis significance testing), endless feuds between frequentists and bayesians, etc. And alas, it does not have a good solution/answer.
Let me start by making an analogy (it is not an analogy: it is a complete and absolute identity) with a situation for which most would have a more intuitive understanding. NHST is exactly the same as a diagnostic test; in diagnostics we ask "do I have Covid"; in NHST we ask "do we have $H_0$?". Both are dichotomous tests (takes only a yes/no answer), in both cases we want to reject $H_0$, so we can accept $H_a$ (I do not have Covid). They both have a sensitivity (Power for NHST=$1-\beta$), they both have a specificity (Confidence=$1-\alpha$ for NHST), they both have a PPV and NPV (positive predictive value and negative predictive value) (for NHST: 1-False Discovery Rate=$1-FDR$, 1-False Omission Rate=$1-FOR$).
And, most important to the question, they will both have a prevalence paradox, or false positive paradox or base-rate paradox (see [wiki][1]). Even if the power (sensitivity) of your test is very high, its FDR (1-PPV) could be very high, if the prevalence of your alternative hypothesis (prevalence of Covid in the population) is low.
Now, let's talk about the p-value, and equation (btw, the OP does not use the most "traditional" of notations here; while understandable, it is a bit confusing). So I will rewrite it a bit w/o changing the OP's point.
p=P(observing the data, or data even more extreme against $H_0$|$H_0$). This is the most general definition.
For notation simplicity, we will simplify it as $p=P(data|H_0)$
And because $H_a$ is the exact logical opposite of $H_0$ (the only way NHST makes any sense: by "disproving" (showing that is is implausible) the opposite of $H_a$, we "prove" (conclude that it is most plausible) $H_a$), we also have $1-p=P(Data|H_a)$.
Unfortunately, we do not really want $P(Data|H_0)$; we really would like $P(H_0|Data)$, and in fact what we really want is $P(H_a|Data)$ (which is  $1-P(H_0|Data)$) (because we do not care about $H_0$, we care about $H_a$)
All of these are conditional probabilities, so indeed we can apply Bayes' theorem to them. So let's do it:
$P(H_a|Data)=\frac{P(Data|H_a).P(H_a)}{P(Data)}$        (1)
Now $P(Data)$ can be decomposed as $P(Data|H_a).P(H_a)+P(Data|H_0).P(H_0)$. We also have $P(Data|H_a)=(1-p)$, and $P(Data|H_0)=p$
We get $P(H_a|Data)=\frac{(1-p).p(H_a)}{(1-p).P(H_a)+p(1-P(H_a))}$ (2)
Or $P(H_a|Data)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{p.(1-P(H_a))}{(1-p).P(H_a)}}$  (3)
So we now have this $P(H_a)$ term. What is it? This is basically the prior probability of your alternative hypothesis (yes, it sounds Baeysian, as expected, because we applied his theorem). What does that mean? That means how likely is it for $H_a$ to be true? This will make some purist frequentists cringe; but as we do not know if $H_a$ is true, there is uncertainty, and if there is uncertainty, we can assign it a probability. You can also understand it as the prevalence of real effects (Colquhoun's interpretation). Or you can understand it as the probability of your study being sufficiently powered to detect an effect. These last 2 are equivalent, and should be palatable to "pure" frequentists.
For example, assuming p=.05 (tradition...), using equation (2), we get:

If $P(H_a)$=.9, $P(H_a|Data)=.994$
If $P(H_a)$=.5, $P(H_a|Data)=.95$
If $P(H_a)$=.05, $P(H_a|Data)=.5$
If $P(H_a)$=.01, $P(H_a|Data)=.161$

Note that in the special case where $P(H_a)=.5$, we have $P(H_a|Data)=P(Data|H_a)=1-p$
As we can see, for the same p-value, I get different answers to the question I really wanted to know (how likely is $H_a$, given the data)... Vexing...
So why do we compute p-values, which are $P(data|H_0)$? Because we can, w/o any estimate of the prior of $P(H_0)$ or $P(H_a)$. In most real life cases, we have no clue about $P(H_a)$, and note that, if we assume 50%/50% for $H_a/H_0$, then the p-value gives us exactly what we wanted...
Should one then use Bayesian statistics? Now you enter the debate of properly chosing the priors? There the choice is between objectively computing what we do not really want to know $(P(Data|H_0))$, or computing what we really want to know $(P(H_a|Data))$, but subjectively. Tough one...
And can we compute something else? If we could, we would have...
Do not however conclude that p-values is a "bad" tool. It is not; it works exactly as advertised. Would you blame mammograms for producing a huge amount of false positives when used on the entire female population? No, you would blame the doctors for not understanding the prevalence of the condition.
Note that this same "prevalence" ($P(H_a)$) also explains, in great part, why "Most Published Research Studies are False" (see [wiki][2] ). Because NHST controls for $\alpha$ errors, but not for FDR (which depends on $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $P(H_a)$. But that is for another answer.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_rate_fallacy#:~:text=An%20example%20of%20the%20base,classifier%20has%20a%20low%20precision).
[2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_Most_Published_Research_Findings_Are_False#:~:text=Given%20the%20realities%20of%20bias,report%20results%20that%20are%20false.

I object to the use of "we" for clearly subjective statements such as "we want to reject $H_0$" (I don't, I'm just curious what the data have to say about it), "we do not really want $P(Data|H_0)$" (you don't know what I want; a frequentist may be quite happy with that), "we do not care about $H_0$" (I normally do). I suggest to replace all "we" by "I" here because it looks very inappropriate to make general statements about what other people want.

@Christian Henning, the OP asks about the p-value, so he is in a frequentist freame. In this frame, the null has only 1 purpose, and that is to be rejected. One only formulates the null as an artifice: it is a reductio ad absurdum argument adapted to statistics. So, while your objection is noted, I will keep the "we", because we compute $P(Data|H_0)$ only because we can not compute $P(H_0|Data)$. Otherwise, we would...

" In this frame, the null has only 1 purpose, and that is to be rejected." - The fact that certain data don't provide evidence against a certain null can be very informative, particularly if the power to detect any relevant alternative is high. (The use of "we" has no implications on your actual statistical message anyway as far as I'm concerned.)

Thank you so much for this answer! Many of your observations were very clarifying. I always struggle with statistical notes and lectures because almost every method makes very strong philosophycal assumptions (not just convenient numerical constraints) without even mentioning they are making it. I wouldn't even mind if they solely mentioned them without accounitng for their validity, but they don't usually even do that and I end up feeling numb for hours because supposedly simple concepts don't click inside me, just to then realize the concept itself is not supposed to click.

When you are discussing having $P(data|H_0)$ while instead being interested in $P(H_0|data)$ you seem to be discussing https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_of_the_inverse . Is this right? (not just a base rate fallacy) Could you give some more words?

@Ggjj11, the 2 (inverse fallacy, false positive paradox) are related, but not the same. Yes, many misinterpret the p-value as $P(H_0|Data)$ when it is fact $P(data|H_0)$. But this misinterpretation has different consequences depending on the "prevalence" ($P(H_a)$): if $p(H_a)$ is >.5, actually $p=P(data|H_0)$ is an underestimate of $P(H_0|data)$ and so your "significant" result is even more significant than you thought. When $p(H_a)=.5$, then the inverse fallacy disappears, and we have $p=P(data|H_0)=P(H_0|data)$. ...cont...

...cont... But as $p(H_a)$ tends to 0, your p-value becomes an overestimate of the evidence against the null, where you false positives (type I errors) far outnumber your true positives. That is the false positive (or base-rate, or prevalence) paradox. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_rate_fallacy
So related (same Bayes theorem at the basis), but not the same.

Very insightful, thank you!
